# How to use a checkbox to change values in an SQL database in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I currently have system which has a web front end and a back office system. User can book properties online or call our office to book a property. In the admin system on the web front, I have two check boxes to determine if the property is available on the front end or the back office system. This is controlled using a Check box. The code for the check box is as follows;

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxAvailableToWeb" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" Text="Available for web bookings"
                                    Checked="true" />
```

I have an field in an SQL Database called "isAvailableToWeb" which has a Boolean result. What I want to achieve is if the check box is checked, the value of the "isAvailableToWeb" field is set to "True" or set to "False" if un-checked.

I have tried to complete this function using the following code;

```
 Protected Sub CheckBoxAvailableToWeb_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, ByVal beachhutid As Long)
    Using dbContext = New bbhasDBEntities
        Dim item
        item = (From i In dbContext.tblBeachHuts Where i.beachHutId = beachhutid Select i).First()
        If CheckBoxAvailableToWeb.Checked = True Then

            item.AvailableToWeb = True
        Else
            item.AvailableToWeb = False
        End If

        dbContext.tblBeachHuts.Attach(item)
        Call dbContext.SaveChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

This code doesn't throw up any errors but doesn't also make the change that I would like to see.

I have a button on this page that saves the information so I would also like to know if it would be better, once the code is working, to put it in that Sub.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false` when assigning values into `AvailableToWeb`.

I use this method with a dataset and it works correctly.

Comment: Tried this method but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `dbContext.SaveChanges` to persist to the database (assuming `bbhasDBEntities` is an instance of DbContext), assign to the entity rather than the boolean and call First() to get the first matching element rather than a collection.

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxAvailableToWeb_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, ByVal beachhutid As Long)
    Using dbContext = New bbhasDBEntities
        Dim item
        item = (From i In dbContext.tblBeachHuts Where i.beachHutId = beachhutid Select i).First()
        If CheckBoxAvailableToWeb.Checked = True Then
            item.AvailableToWeb = True
        Else
            item.AvailableToWeb = False
        End If
        Call dbContext.SaveChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. When trying to use the Call bdContext.SaveChanges(), I receive an error stating, "bdContext is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level". Any ideas?

Comment: Should be "dbContext" not "bdContext" my typo in my OP, apologies.

Comment: No problem. I have made the relevant change but still doesn't seem to be updating in the database.

Comment: See updated code. You were assigning directly to a boolean, not to the entity. Try that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but there is no longer a "AvailableToWeb" variable to reference now that it has been changed to "item". Is there a typo?

Comment: Add First() to the end of the query as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. The code is running fine but there is still no update in the database. Should I try to impliment this code into the "btnSave_Click" sub so these changes are made when the button is clicked?

Comment: Should make a different providing the function fires. Have you placed breakpoints in the code to check it is firing?

Comment: I've but some breakpoints around the sub and under the break points all the conditions are set to (no condition) and the Hit Count's are all (currently 0). Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the ByVal beachhutid As Long getting its value from?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I have picked this project up after around 3 other people have worked on it and have very beginner level of VB.NET and ASP.NET. Do I have to assign it a value somehow?

Comment: Immediately before the save try dbContext.tblBeachHuts.Attach(item). Does this work?

Comment: I have edited my question with the most up to date code. I have implemented what you have suggested but there is still no change to the database :(